# Sonarqube scheduled analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Can SonarQube automatically analyse our sourcecode for us at any specified time? Do we have to manually analyze the code always? I just started using SonarQube and couldn't find anything on this question on Google or Sonar's website.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no built-in scheduling in SonarQube. Most people use jobs (dedicated or not) in some continuous integration engine (Jenkins, Bamboo, etc.) for their analyses.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube itself cant do any analysis. Analysis can be done only thorough SonarQube Runner, Build tools (ANT,MAVEN,Gradle)and Build Automation tool / CI tools.
Scheduling can be done through Build Automation Tool / CI tools.

For Jenkins: You can follow this documentation.
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+SonarQube+on+Jenkins+Job